# CSS position property clarification

Tags: css, css-position

So I have created this page(Sorry I couldn't get the code snippet to render image for some reason)

https://codepen.io/704621168/pen/bxdmXE

I have managed to create the desired effect. But there is one thing that I am confused about the code.

I have only used position:absolute on the inner divs. Therefore all the other elements have position:static by default. In that case why aren't they overlapping? Is it because I have explicitly defined the height and width of the sections that contain them?

```
* {
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;

text-align: center;
color: white;

font-family: Tangerine;

}
div {
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;

width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
max-width: 100%;

}
section{
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
max-width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 3vh;
}
.container{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;

height: auto;
width: auto;

}



.bgimg{
background-attachment: scroll;
background-size: cover;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;

filter: blur(50px);

}

.fgimg{
position: absolute;
background-size: contain;
z-index: 1;
}

.img1{
background-image: url("http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/1    /7/2/411287.jpg");
}
.img2{
background-image: url("http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/a/4/f/411316.jpg");
}
.img3{
background-image: url("http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/2/2/f/411339.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? There is nothing visible in the output of your snippet

Comment: From what I can gather, the sections are all appearing separately even though there are no other positioned elements in the code - despite common knowledge of position:absolute; being that they would all overlap.

Comment: Your sections have defined dimensions, so they don’t rely on their content to “span them up” in the first place. You could remove those image-divs completely or set them to display:none, that would not make these sections collapse either.